# get null values with decode

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a table with names, where the name can be null.
If I want to get all the rows with null names,
I do the following:

```
select * from table1 where name is null;
```

but I want to make sure that if I specify a value it will get the non-null values and if it won't get the null values

```
select * from table1 where name in decode (: var, null, name)
```

So I get the values that are not null when the var is null, how can I get the values that are null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a null-safe equality. In Oracle, that would look like:

```
where name = :var or (name is null and :var is null)
```

The condition succeeds if either of the following conditions is true:

- the values are equal (this implies that none of them is `null`)
- both values are `null`

If you know in advance a value that is not available in the column, you can use `coalesce()` or `nvl()`:

```
where nvl(name, 'N/A') = nvl(:var, 'N/A')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with DECODE.  But you just need to adjust how you are using it.  As DECODE handles NULLs appropriately, the following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t
WHERE DECODE(:var, t.name, 1, 0) = 1;
```

From the 19c [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE):

> In a DECODE function, Oracle considers two nulls to be equivalent. If expr is null, then Oracle returns the result of the first search that is also null.